# Objective-C first launch code is ignored

Tags: objective-c

I'm *VERY* new to Xcode but I am looking to add some extra functionality to my basic app. This functionality should log a string upon first launch. For debugging purposes I have also asked the program to output a string even if it's not first launch. I can't seem to find these messages anywhere (I'm assuming Xcode would snap to them like most IDEs). Am I doing this in the right file? The application uses the tab bar controller.

Thanks

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//
//  Created by Joel Kidd on 29/05/2013.
//
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {
        NSLog(@"This is not the first launch.");
    } else {
        // Place first launch code here
        NSLog(@"This is the first launch!");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: All `NSLog` messages should appear into the debug area panel (View>Debug Area>Activate Console), also `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of your app delegate would be the ideal place to check for a first launch. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: Perfect! Placing it in the app delegate seemed to fix it! Thanks very much! (Why not submit that as an answer? :D)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All `NSLog` messages should appear into the debug area panel (View>Debug Area>Activate Console), also `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` of your app delegate would be the ideal place to check for a first launch (on your example, the code would be executed each time your controller's view would be loaded).